# PHP feof($file) returns false on the empty file

Tags: php

There is php code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
if ($file = fopen("file.txt", "r")) {
        while(!feof($file)) {
                $line = fgets($file);
                echo "----" , $line , "----";
            }
        fclose($file);
}
?>
```

and empty file "file.txt"

```
[root@localhost]# ls -l  file.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Апр 21 10:14 file.txt
[root@localhost]# file file.txt 
file.txt: empty
```

Why i get ? feof should be true in first loop or am i wrong?

```
[root@localhost ]# php -f  test2.php
--------

[root@localhost ]#
```

Comment: There is a huge writeup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php#67261 from the manul.

Comment: To clarify: if you haven't read anything from the file through `fgets`, the end of the file hasn't been reached yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is because the file is already empty but PHP doesn't know it until it executes the `fgets()` method.

In order to avoid PHP reads the first empty line, you have to check that `fgets` is not `false`. To achieve that should do something like:

```php
if ($file = fopen("file.txt", "r")) {
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        echo "----" , $line , "----";
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```